# Rouge links to my website to pages called ineeta .php - is this a concern?

Tags: security, wordpress, sql-injection, spam

In Google Anlytics I am getting hundreds of hits to pages which don't exist on my website which I assume are some sort of spam or bot realted thing.

I want to make sure that this isn't going to cause any issues to my site or be a security risk.

My website URL is imageworkshop.com, and the links that I am seeing are to the following paths on this domain:

- /imagework/ineeta.V1.02.07.php
- /imagework/ineeta.V1.02.13.php
- /imagework/ineeta.V1.02.15.php
- /imagework/ineeta.V1.03.01.php
- /imagework/ineeta.V1.02.16.php
- /imagework/ineeta.V1.02.08.php

Each of these pages is showing 150-300 page views (they just show 404 errors).

Average time on page shows 2-4 minutes for these.

Source of link shows as (direct) in google analytics.

Is this some kind of attempt at a brute force / SQL injection attack?
The visits have all happened 3-4 days apart through the month of October 2011.

Any suggestions on what this is or if I should be concerned?

The website is built on wordpress and does have a few plugins used - there is always a possibilty that these links are related to a plugin I guess?
I have wordpress up to date with the latest version (currently 3.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably right. As long as those pages don't exist on your server there is no security risk.